# http post inside .then()

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I want to do a http post inside `.then()`. I've already it in many diferent ways...nothing worked
I'm trying to create an user and do an http `POST` after the creation.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
 return function(req, res, next) {
const body = req.body;

// Get the user service and `create` a new user
app.service('users').create({
  email: body.email,
  password: body.password
}).then('I WANT HTTP POST WITH PARAMS HERE')
// On errors, just call our error middleware
.catch(next);

};
};
```

I want to send email and password in the `POST`

Answer (score 2):

You can return a Promise in promise chain. I would use promisified request to do a postAsync here.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var request =  Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'))

app.service('users').create({
        email: body.email,
        password: body.password
    }).then(function(createUserResp) {
        return request.postAsync(/**/)
    })
     }).then(function(resp) {
        // do sth
    })
    .catch(next);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var RP = require('request-promise')

app.service('users').create({
    email: body.email,
    password: body.password
}).then(function () {
    var opt = {
        url: 'targetUrl', 
        formData: {
            email: body.email,
            password: body.password
            //, json: true // if result is in json format 
        }
    }
    return RP.post(opt)
}).then(function (postResult) {

})
.catch(next);
```